# Can I choose which ads will be displayed to me on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, advertising

The reason why is that I found SO Careers ads very distracting. Right now I'm not really looking for a job, but it's very difficult to ignore the good offers. I would like to see other kind of ads.

Comment: Sounds like the ads are working